# Why is my function is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`TaskQueue: Error with task : undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._renderReplies(replyCount)')`

I'm getting this error above.

```
_renderReplies = (replyCount) => {
    return (<Text>`View ${replyCount} replies`</Text>);
}

_renderItem(row) {
           ...
        <View>{this._renderReplies(replyCount)}</View> <- Getting an error here
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Why am I getting undefined function error???? So weird.

Comment: i think you forgot to bind `_renderItem` method, because of that, check.

Comment: I don't think I need to bind it because I'm using this syntax `_renderReplies = (replyCount) =>` Should I still need to bind it??

Comment: but you are not using arrow function with `_renderItem`, use the same way it will work :)

Comment: um it didn't solve the problem

Comment: can you show how you are calling/using `_renderItem` method, i am sure this is related to binding only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind your `_renderItem` function to the `class`;

Either use an `arrow` function (like you did with `_renderReplies`) that will bind it automatically

```
_renderItem = (row) => {
           ...
        <View>{this._renderReplies(replyCount)}</View> <- Getting an error here
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Or bind it in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._renderItem = this._renderItem.bind(this);
}
_renderItem(row) {
           ...
        <View>{this._renderReplies(replyCount)}</View> <- Getting an error here
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**_renderItem** does not have access to this. You can either use an arrow function or bind this inside the constructor. Arrow functions always have access to this.

**Arrow functions method :**

```
_renderItem = (row) => {
           ...
        <View>{this._renderReplies(replyCount)}</View> <- Getting an error here
      </View>
    )
}

_renderReplies = (replyCount) => {
    return (<Text>`View ${replyCount} replies`</Text>);
}
```

**Bind method :**

```
constructor(props) {
   this._renderItem = this._renderItem.bind(this)
   this._renderReplies = this._renderReplies.bind(this)
}

_renderItem(row) {
           ...
        <View>{this._renderReplies(replyCount)}</View> <- Getting an error here
      </View>
    )
}

_renderReplies(replyCount) {
    return (<Text>`View ${replyCount} replies`</Text>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Sag1v posted a same answer with yours, so I just accepted his. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use the this keyword when you call _renderReplies()